# Haskell Creating list of numbers

Tags: list, haskell

Hi
Im new to Haskell and wish to write a simple code.
I want to write a function which creates a list of numbers.
Where it starts of with 1 and increase with 2n+1 and 3n+1
so for example output should be like
take 6 myList = [1,3,4,7,9,10]

I think i need to use recursion but not sure how to do
it in list format.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your example has all outputs sorted, which creates an odd interleaving pattern.  Do you need them to be sorted (infinitely that is-- if you just want finitely many you could always sort afterward)?  What about duplicates; i.e. if some number can be written as 2n+1 and 3m+1, where n and m are elements of the list, should it appear twice?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, I am not sure if I get your idea. 
But Is this what you want?

```
generator list = list ++ generator next
    where
    next = (map (\n -> 2 * n + 1) list) ++ (map (\n -> 3 * n + 1) list)
```

Oh, you can use generator [1] to fire up. like this:

```
take 100 $ generator [1]
```

Comment: +1 Wow, elegant solution.  I was reaching for priority queues and stuff.

Comment: This is slightly deceptive as it is "more sorted" but still not sorted or nubbed.

Answer (score 1):

```
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) | x == y = x : merge xs ys
                    | x < y = x : merge xs (y:ys)
                    | otherwise = y : merge (x:xs) ys 

print $ take 10 $ merge [1,3..] [1,4..]
--[1,3,4,5,7,9,10,11,13,15]
```

Comment: This seems to be wrong, he said the first several items are  [1,3,4,7,9,10]. but yours produce [1,3,4,5,7,9,10].

Comment: But 5 is of the form 2n + 1, isn't it? Or did I mistunderstand the question?

Comment: I think the `n` must be a preceding part of the list for `2n+1` to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

As luqui said, we could use info such as do duplicates matter and does order matter.  If the answers are no and no then a simple concatMap works fine:

```
myList = 1 : concatMap (\n -> 2*n+1 : 3*n+1 : []) myList
```

Results in:

```
> take 20 myList
[1,3,4,7,10,9,13,15,22,21,31,19,28,27,40,31,46,45,67,43]
```

If the answers are yes and yes then I imagine it could be cleaner, but this is sufficient:

```
myList = abs
  where
  abs = merge as bs
  as = 1 : map (\n -> 2*n+1) abs
  bs = 1 : map (\n -> 3*n+1) abs
  merge (x:xs) (y:ys)
        | x == y = x : merge xs ys
        | x < y  = x : merge xs (y:ys)
        | otherwise = y : merge (x:xs) ys
```

Results in:

```
> take 20 myList
[1,3,4,7,9,10,13,15,19,21,22,27,28,31,39,40,43,45,46,55]
```